# core dumped when i use fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to read a text file with the function `fscanf`, but everytime I get a "core dumped". It's weird because when I use another file that I already use somewhere else, the code doesn't work too and I found no syntax errors.

my function code :

```
 inst_def_t* lect_dico_int(char* nomFichierDico, int* p_nb_inst) {
  /*Charge le ficheier dictionnaire nomFichierDico*/
  /*Retourne un pointeur sur le tableau dictionnaire*/
  /*Stocke le nb d'instructions dans *p_nb_inst*/

int i;
char s1[512];
inst_def_t *tab;
FILE* f1=open(nomFichierDico,"r");
printf("step 1 \n");
if(f1==NULL)
      return NULL;
    }
printf("step 2 \n");
fscanf(f1,"%d", p_nb_inst);
printf("step 3 \n");
  fclose(f1);
  return tab; /* here i just want to have my fscaf working not really matter of tab value */
}
```

my main code :

```
int main()
{ 
  int NbDefInstructions = 0 ;
  inst_def_t* = lect_dico_int("tests/DICO_INSTRUCTION.txt",&NbDefInstructions);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the structure :

```
typedef struct {char * symbole; char type; int nb_op ;} inst_def_t;
```

and here my .txt :

```
4
ADD R 3
ADDI I 2
MULT R 2
DIV R 2
```

When i use my code i get to "step 2" but when it arrives to the function `fscanf` I got a segmentation fault (core dumped).
I just want to know where is my error, that prevent me to use the function `fscanf`.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Comment: What error does it give you when it blows up?

Comment: You are never returning something from `lect_dico_int`.

Comment: Don't show code snippets but show a [mcve]

Comment: What is `path`? Please [edit]  your question and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overrunning an allocated memory buffer:

```
char* path2=strdup("tests/");
strcat(path,"DICO_INSTRUCTION.txt");
```

The `strdup` function allocates just enough space for the given string.  When you then use `strcat` to append to that string, you're writing past the bounds of the memory that was allocated.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a core dump.

Either pass the full string to `strdup`:

```
char* path=strdup("tests/DICO_INSTRUCTION.txt");
```

Or, if the second string is not constant, or use `asprintf` to create a string and allocate space for it:

```
char *filename = "DICO_INSTRUCTION.txt";
char *path;
asprintf(&path, "tests/%s", filename);
```

Your other problem is here:

```
FILE* f1=open(nomFichierDico,"r");
```

You're calling `open`, which returns a numerical file descriptor, instead of `fopen`, which returns a pointer to a `FILE` object.  You want:

```
FILE* f1=fopen(nomFichierDico,"r");
```

Comment: Isn't `asprintf` a non standard gcc extension?

Comment: I use your correction but i still got a seg fault when the function `scanf`is used

Comment: @AdrienRabier then there may be other problems elsewhere in the code you didn't show. You need to provide a [MCVE]. You can edit your question.

Comment: @AdrienRabier  You're using `open` instead of `fopen`.  See my edit.